# URL Regular Expression matching exact 3 characters after decimal

Tags: regex

I require regular expression to match exactly 3 or 2 characters after decimal point, so that it validates www.xyz.com and not xyz.Complete

Comment: I have used this expression "[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)" , to match but it is matching xyz.Complete and xyz.Completion text also, which should not be the case

Comment: What about .co.uk addresses, or .info, or .museum? The list could go on...

Comment: while I tried to provide information that I think you need in your case in my answer below, what you seem to be trying to do is going to fail or give you a headache at some point - _real life_ URLS are CONSIDERABLY more complex than your expression can handle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `\b`

I can't think of a case that's not reasonably covered by using the word-boundary assertion `\b` any of the other answers need only have `\b` at the end (if it's always `.com`, then you'd use `.com\b` which means essentially a literal dot (`.`) character followed by `com`, where whatever follows is something other than a letter, number or underscore. It's a zero-width assertion, which means it will not capture anything. To allow a `.net` or `.edu` as well, you would use `\.(com|edu|net)\b`

The `\b` assertion is supported in most tools and languages using regexes, but if you need to get more precise (for instance, you might want to allow an underscore after `com`), your tool or language compiler may support "lookaheads" which are also zero-width assertions. (in the instance mentioned just above, you would use something like `\.(com|net|edu|org|mil|museum)(?![a-zA-Z0-9])` which would prohibit numbers and uppercase or lowercase letters)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly answering your question of

> match exactly 3 or 2 characters after decimal point

To match just the ending:

```
\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}$
```

the `\` escapes the `.` which otherwise means "any character"

Comment: With the side note it will accept any top level domain instead of those specified in the question. I don't know the intention but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: cann you help me modify this expression "[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)" so that it takes ony 2 or 3 characters after decimal?

Comment: Replace the whole `OR` ( `\.(com|...` )expression with the one I gave. For the expression I specified to work, the top level domain must be at the end of the string.

Comment: I replaced the ( \.(com|... ) like us said, but now its replacing exactly 3 characters of any word that begin after decimal, eg. if the word is "...xyz.completion.." than it displays" xyz.xxxpletion" which should not be the case

Comment: @user1158326 - Not sure what you are trying to replace, but if you take @beerbajay's sub-expression your should now be `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}$`. It will ony match valid 2 or 3 letter at the end. If you want to repair it use `^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.)([A-Za-z]{4,})$` check bad in $2, then replace match with whatever you want, like `$1com`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the string beginning and ending checks (`^`, `$`). Use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

Comment: This is assuming that `xyz.com/index.html` is invalid.  Other things that pass: `..com`, `-.com`, `ten.-.-.-.-.-.-.net`.

Comment: I had orginally used it, but don't know why, it still did not validate "**www.google.com**" or "refer my website at @ **google.com**"

Comment: @user1158326 What exactly do you want to validate? Just a domain name? Or any web address? Or a domain name inside some random string?

Comment: I want to validate domain names inside a description field, now my description is multi-lined and dynamic, it can contain the website url somewhere in middle, in the form of **www.xyz.com** or http://www.xyz.com or http://xyz.com or text like "contact us @ **xyz.com** (the extension can be ), if http:// does not get replaced, no issues but url must get replaced